# Query running for days

Tags: sqlite

I have a big SQLITE Database with ~2B row of 4 columns with 1 index (140GB).
I made a query for remove duplicate of 2 fields:

```
delete   from DATA
where    rowid not in
         (
         select  min(rowid)
         from    DATA
         group by
                 Field1
         ,       Field2
         )
```

Its now running for 4 days:

- Day 1 & 2: Created 3 etilqs temp file for a total of ~90GB
- Day 3 & today: Started writing the db-journal which is now 20GB..

The writing speed is very slow now and I need this job done very soon!

How much time should I wait? How big can the db-journal be?

For next time, how could I improve the query to make it much faster?

Thx!

Comment: What's the [EXPLAIN QUERY PLAN](https://www.sqlite.org/eqp.html) output for that?

Comment: I don't know, haven't tried. I will set eqp on next time, thx for the tip

Comment: For now db-journal still growing..